# Why I get all this error when initializing my AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Actually, I'm interested in know if by correcting any of this errors I can improve the performance of the AVD, which is too slow.

I'm on Android Studio 1.3.2, with Android SDK 6 and Java SDK 8. On a Intel i3 with 4GB RAM (~1.5GB free).

AVD: Nexus_5_API_23_x86 with 512MB RAM.

The complete errors log from Logcat is here:
http://pastebin.com/UReeY720

It starts with

```
09-04 23:02:09.902        0-945/? E/lowmemorykiller? Kernel does not support memory pressure events or in-kernel low memory killer
09-04 23:02:10.688      965-965/? E/perfprofd? unable to open configuration file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/perfprofd.conf
09-04 23:02:11.470      958-958/? E/? batterystats service unavailable!
09-04 23:02:11.470      958-958/? E/? batterystats service unavailable!
09-04 23:02:11.491      958-958/? E/? batterystats service unavailable!
```

and ends with

```
09-04 23:04:37.002     958-1286/? E/Drm? Failed to find drm plugin
09-04 23:04:40.318    1800-1828/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode? A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
            at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
            at com.android.okhttp.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:62)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.unzip(HttpEngine.java:645)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:811)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:776)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:676)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:660)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.j.a(SourceFile:220)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:263)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:132)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.b.a(SourceFile:43)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.b.a(SourceFile:62)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:120)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:61)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.cron.AuthCronService.a(SourceFile:44)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.al.run(SourceFile:135)
09-04 23:04:41.365    1743-2123/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/MDM? [93] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
```

(all this was just by initializing the AVD, I didn't run my app)

Comment: Use genymotion, its way lighter and less painful.

Comment: did you have internet connection by then? @AdilSoomro that sounds to me like spam.

Comment: @Elltz and why is that? I think its better option than using the memory hungry and slow default android's avd.